# C++: How to get the type (file or folder) and permissions of children in a directory?

Tags: c++, operating-system

How to get the type (file or folder) and permissions (e.x. read, write, and execute permissions for the owner) of children in a directory? Write now, the below code is able to list the names of all the children in a directory (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-program-list-files-sub-directories-directory/), but I'm wondering if there's a method I can use to get the type (file or folder) and their permissions (e.x. calling a method on `de` to get its type and permissions).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
  
int main(void)
{
    struct dirent *de;  // Pointer for directory entry
  
    // opendir() returns a pointer of DIR type. 
    DIR *dr = opendir(".");
  
    if (dr == NULL)  // opendir returns NULL if couldn't open directory
    {
        printf("Could not open current directory" );
        return 0;
    }
  
    // Refer http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/xsh/readdir.html
    // for readdir()
    while ((de = readdir(dr)) != NULL)
            printf("%s\n", de->d_name);
  
    closedir(dr);    
    return 0;
}
```

*Important*: I **cannot** use any methods or built-in libraries later than C++11.

Comment: Since C++17 there's [the filesystem library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem). In particular there's [std::filesystem::status](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/status) which can lead you to [permissions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/file_status/permissions).

Comment: @NathanPierson Please see the updated important note in my question :D.

Comment: If you are using C++11, you can very well use Boost's [`boost::filesystem`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html) from which `std::filesystem` was derived in the first place.